# Bounding box for C++ particle system not working

Tags: c++, physics, bounding-box, particles, particle-system

I have created a particle system in c++ using Qt which includes gravity. I would like to include a bounding box so that the system can also include collisions however I cannot seem to get it to work. Here is my .h code:

```
typedef struct {
    int top;
    int bottom;
    int left;
    int right;

}BoundingBox;

BoundingBox makeBoundingBox(int top, int bottom, int left, int right);
```

.cpp:

```
BoundingBox makeBoundingBox(int top, int bottom, int left, int right)
{
    BoundingBox boundingBox;
    boundingBox.top = top;
    boundingBox.bottom = bottom;
    boundingBox.left = left;
    boundingBox.right = right;

    return boundingBox;
}
```

I have then updated the bounding box in my emitter class using this loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<m_numParticles; ++i)
    {

        if (m_pos.m_y >= _boundingBox.top)
        {
            m_dir.m_y = (-1)*(m_dir.m_y);
        }

        if (m_pos.m_y <= _boundingBox.bottom)
        {
            m_dir.m_y = (-1)*(m_dir.m_y);
        }

        if (m_pos.m_x <= _boundingBox.left)
        {
            m_dir.m_x = (-1)*(m_dir.m_x);
        }

        if (m_pos.m_x >= _boundingBox.right)
        {
            m_dir.m_x = (-1)*(m_dir.m_x);
        }

        m_particles[i].update(m_gravity, _boundingBox);
```

And have set the bounding box in my window as so:

```
m_emitter->setBoundingBox(makeBoundingBox(m_height, 0, 0, m_width));
```

I am not getting any errors however it doesn't seem to be working,
Any advice would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What does "it not working" mean in this context?  Be careful with simple box-box intersection tests in physics.  It's possible for them to go right through each other if the velocity is > the box size.

Comment: I would try putting some cout statements in your function that checks for collisions to see what kind of numbers your function is getting, and see if your if statements are ever true. Are you doing transformations on the particles themselves? If so check that your transformations are being applied to the bounding boxes too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that decreasing X means going towards left and decreasing Y means going towards top, your conditions seem incorrect. I would also update the position alongside the velocity to make sure it doesn't get triggered multiple times in a row.

Example for the Y coordinate:

```
// Are we going up too much?
if (m_pos.m_y < _boundingBox.top)
{
    m_dir.m_y = (-1)*(m_dir.m_y);
    m_pos.m_y = _boundingBox.top + 1;
}
// Or are we going down too much?
else if (m_pos.m_y > _boundingBox.bottom)
{
    m_dir.m_y = (-1)*(m_dir.m_y);
    m_pos.m_y = _boundingBox.bottom - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't:

```
m_emitter->setBoundingBox(makeBoundingBox(m_height, 0, 0, m_width));
```

Be:

```
m_emitter->setBoundingBox(makeBoundingBox(0, m_height, 0, m_width));
```